# Problems implementing a itoa function with printf and without it

Tags: c, pointers, itoa

I just write a code for my own itoa (just for positive numbers) and I try  to make it as efficient possible, I display the value from inside the function and from main, and it works, but when I remove the printf line from inside the function the code doesn't work anymore, does anybody knows why?

This is where it works

[image]

This is where it doesn't work

[image]

Thank you for your time!
have a nice day

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define uint8_t unsigned char
#define uint16_t unsigned int

/*Prototipos de funciones*/
uint8_t *UART0_itoa(uint16_t number, uint8_t base);

/*Función principal*/
void main(){
    uint8_t *cadena;
    cadena = UART0_itoa(255, 16);
    printf("The String in main: %s\n",cadena);
}

/*Declaración de funciones*/
uint8_t *UART0_itoa(uint16_t number, uint8_t base){
  uint8_t *aux;
  *aux = '\0';
  while(number){
    *--aux = (number%base>9)?(number%base)+'7':(number%base)+'0';
    number/=base;
  }
  //printf("The String in the function: %s\n",aux);
  return aux;
}
```

Comment: `aux` is a pointer. It does not point anywhere valid; you have not assigned (or initialized with) any value. `*aux = '\0';` invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `uint8_t *aux; *aux = '\0';` but you have not initialised `aux`.

Comment: I try uint8_t *aux = NULL; 
and then *aux = '\0';
but still doesn't work, is there any other way?

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: Don't use `#define` as a `typedef` substitute, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not allocating any memory to `aux` - it is an uninitialized pointer. Anything that you write to it, including the initial assignment of `*aux = '\0'`, is undefined behavior.

You need to change the code to take the output buffer, or allocate it dynamically with `malloc`. An attempt to write the number backwards is a nice one - you can make it work by passing the end of buffer, as follows:

```
uint8_t *UART0_itoa(uint16_t number, uint8_t base, char *aux){
    while(number){
        *--aux = (number%base>9)?(number%base)+'7':(number%base)+'0';
        number/=base;
    }
    return aux;
}
```

and calling

```
char buf[16];
cadena = UART0_itoa(255, 16, &buf[15]);
```